# How to make web service available for cross-domain access in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, web

I'm building a nodejs server and I need to access more services using ajax from another domain, so how can I break the cross-domain restriction in nodejs code?

Note: Frameworks like ExpressJS is not an acceptable solution

Comment: All you really need to break the cross-domain access is the callback method approach. There is much documentation about it. JSONP I believe. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: Could you write an example for it in an answer?

Comment: Close your question. Here is a complete answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain

Comment: Essentially all you are doing is forcing the consumer to setup a function on their end to handle the request.

Comment: but this is not a nodejs solutions, this post is for php

Comment: The JSONP link at the top of the answer explains JSONP with documentation. It's all done via javascript. Nothing really special to do server side.

Comment: @Leeish With all respect, your reply is incomplete. JSONP only works when the server supports it. A better, modern solution would be CORS.

Comment: @HazemHagrass Do you need to offer cross-domain access of third-party websites via your server? If so, then take a look at https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere. It's a reverse proxy that enables CORS on proxied requests, written in Node.js.

Answer (score -1):

Generally speaking, when there is a cross domain restriction in effect you have two possible options to take.

1. Determine if the remote party you're trying to talk to supports [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). Have them allow your domain on their end in the HTTP headers. Sometimes this is not possible.
2. Setup a reverse HTTP proxy that allows you to communicate to the remote party but goes through your web server first so you bypass the cross domain origin security issue. [Node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) is a possible solution if you're already using Node.js

CORS is generally only supported in [more recent browsers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/), so if you have a requirement to support old stuff that might not be suitable.

Note in jQuery from linked resource.

> $.support.cors

boolean will be set to true if the browser supports CORS